# How do I use mod_rewrite to redirect to a URL including something not in the old URL?

Tags: mod-rewrite

I want to redirect every archive pages on my blog to new directories
but I don't know how to mod rewrite in htaccess file.

It might not be possible to do this because I added extra date variable in the new url?

OLD URL
http://www.url.com/blog/2010/03/blog-entry.html

NEW URL
http://www.url.com/blog/2010-03-05/blog-entry/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, unfortunately the new variable will cause a problem. If you can use the other parts to identify the missing value then you can use `RewriteMap` to call a script to retrieve it for you, otherwise you are SOL.

Comment: Thanks for the quick one!
I will figure out another way.